# Get ng-model values on POST to Express.js endpoint

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am creating a Node.js application with AngularJS.

I want to make a simple POST, using Angular. This POST should post a couple of values to my server, where I can see them using `console.log`.

In my HTML code, I build it with the `ng-model` and a button that has a `ng-click`.

I can tell my Node.js server is being hit, as it outputs the `post called` in the console.

However, I have been trying to read about how to read the POST values, but I haven't found a solution.

How would I modify my code to read `serialKey` and `gameTitle` in my Express.js endpoint?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group" ng-controller="CreateController">
    <p>Serial key:<br/>
        <input class="form-control"  ng-model="serialKey" />
    </p>

    <p>Game:<br/>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="gameTitle" />
    </p>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="postNewIsbn(serialKey,gameTitle)">Add</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Angular controller code:**

```
app.controller('CreateController',function($scope, $http) {
    var url = '/api/serials';
    $scope.postNewIsbn = function(serial, game) {
        $http.post(url, {
            serial: serial,
            gametitle: game
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.data.status = 'success';
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            $scope.data.error = error;
        });
    };
});
```

**Express.js endpoint**

```
app.post('/api/serials',function(req,res){

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('post called');
});
```

Comment: in your ng-click function you getting values for serial and game arguments?

Comment: What you getting in req.body?

Comment: @V31 I get undefined when I say console.log(req.body)

Comment: body-parser middleware https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the problem of setting content-type header. In your angular application you can set defaultHeaders for your post request just after you initialize the module or in your config function with this line

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
```

Do remember to inject the $httpProvider dependency whereever you setting this header

**UPDATE**

It may be the case that you need to configure your express in order to use the bodyParser with this line:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

## req.param(*name*)

When attempting to retrieve data passed with the request, the `req.param()` function checks the following in order to find the parameter:

1. `req.params`
2. `req.body`
3. `req.query`

See the docs [here](http://expressjs.com/api#req.param).

Also, try explicitly setting the content-type header in the POST request to "application/json".

Comment: Hm. If I say "console.log(req.param('gameTitle'))", and I make sure the ng-model and JSON post from the Angular app is called gameTitle, I still get undefined.. any idea why?

Comment: Just to be sure, is the $http.post success callback running after the request completes? Better yet, could you post the request/response data from the browser console?

Comment: In your example your POST variable is gametitle not gameTitle